# Disabling item in a ListView when having something in a spinner selected

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, spinner

I'm currently creating an app where I need to have an item selected from a Spinner, and then click the submit button. Based on what's clicked, the ListView needs to have certain items disappear, basically creating an entirely new array.

The catch is: each element in this ListView has a specific type associated with it (type1, type2, etc.). In the Spinner, if I select type1 in the Spinner, for example, only items in the ListView with the type1 should show up. Everything else should disappear.

I've built a hash map where I'm able to associate every element in the ListView with a type, for further reasons. I just need help disabling the items in this ListView when I have a Spinner item selected when I click that submit button.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: you need custom adapter, you need handle that in `getView`, you can use `ConvertView.SetVisibility(View.Gone)` for each item that you don't want

Comment: With the use of Custom Adapter you can disappear items easilt, bechause it will create new arr every time

Comment: So I would have to create a new adapter class? I have one created for ALL items. Would I have to create one for a specific class?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your adapter and remove the items that you don't want to show. Then call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the adapter.

The ListView will refresh itself.

Comment: Now, should I do this in the addListenerOnButton() method where I create the activity for the submit button?

Comment: As soon as the user has selected an option in the spinner.